# Bring the data module to work with --- pass-Store-use a connection inside a reusable data module

Tags: asp.net, data-access, state-management

I want to seperate the data module of a site into an assembly ( a single dll file ) ,
What is the best way to **get-store and pass** the **ConnectionString** of the site in dealing with the web application .
Inside the data assembly I made a static class named ConnectionManager . It has a property named **DatabaseConnectionName**  , that I want to pass and store the connection namewhich is inside Web.Config file .
In this strategy I decided to get the name and make the connection in the load time of the website at the Global.asax file and stroe that in the property I mentioned earlier ( DatabaseConnectionName ) .
But , This is just the strategy that I used , I dont know what is the **common pattern** for doing this job .

**Parts of code :** =====================================
[ ------------  **Global.asax** ------------ ]

```
the code in the site that makes the Data module accessible for the site
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         OurCompany.Data.ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnectionName = "MasterConnection";
    }
```

[ ------------  **ConnectionManager Class** ------------ ]
this is in the data module apart from the site

```
public static class ConnectionManager
{

    public static SqlConnection  GetMasterConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[**DatabaseConnectionName**].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn;     
        //conn.Open();
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return  conn;
    }

    private static string **databaseConnectionName**;
    public static string DatabaseConnectionName
    {
        get
        {
            return databaseConnectionName;
        }
        set
        {
            databaseConnectionName = value;
        }
    }
```

== END ===========================================================

**--- Questions are  : ---**

1. Where to store the connection ?
   ( here was a property inside the ConnectionManager Class ,
   theCompany.Data.ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnectionName )
2. When make this connection ?
   ( here was at Global.asax Application Load time )
3. Which method is best for storing such information 
     : SessionState or ViewState or a simple property
4. Is this strategy good ? Do you know any better way or
    the common pattern for this ?

Thanks for any information
- MHM -

Comment: My Friend ,
I checked that there were really little differences between that structure & mine , Just I used static with a reason , & I passedthe name of db to my method , in other hand ENT.DAL just use a static name for its db (e.g Mydatabese ) .Also it is good always to problem of a code u written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts...

1. You shouldn't be storing and hanging onto an open database connection. Open the connection, do your database operations, then close immediately. Apply the rule of acquire late, release early.
2. See point 1.
3. Don't store database connections in session state. See point 1 again. If you mean the connection string, then just read it from the configuration manager when you need it. It's already cached for you, don't re-invent or wrap the wheel.
4. I suggest you take a look at the patterns and practices enterprise library which abstracts away many of the common patterns of managing data access:

http://www.codeplex.com/entlib

Comment: You are right , my friend ,
but ,The property I defined is for just keeping the name of the databse northe connectionString ,
If you look at my code , you will get my idea .
I open and close immediately , thats right .
About EntLib , I'm sure that It'll help me , but I have a very limited time .

Comment: It'll take you about 30mins to get your head around entlib, it's really straight forward.

Comment: Thanks ,
I'll go for it ,
I hope to find something related to my problem .

Comment: My Friend , I checked that there were really little differences between that structure & mine , Just I used static with a reason , & I passedthe name of db to my method , in other hand ENT.DAL just use a static name for its db (e.g Mydatabese ) .Also it is good always to find the problem.Could you ?